# How to make next, previous links for data fetched from database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pagination

I had made a page to fetch data from mysql database. I want to show only 10 result per page and other result using next button and previous result using previous button.

I used the following code to fetch data:

```
$item=$_POST('item');
$query=mysql_query("select name,address,contact from info_tb where keyword='$item'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array('$query'))
{
echo "Name : row[0]":
echo "Address : row[1]":
echo "Contact : row[2]":
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) keyword on your mySQL Query.

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 10
```

Seems like you want to navigate records, so ..

```
 SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 5, 10
```

These records will be displayed 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15

If you want to navigate you need to control this paramter as illustrated.

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 5, 10
                                 ^
```

Seems like you posted code lately, Try something like this on your code.

```
$item=$_POST['item'];
$page=$_POST['pno'];
$query=mysql_query("select name,address,contact from info_tb where keyword='$item' limit '$page',10");
```

Comment: But that's not what he's asking. He doesn't want to limit the results of the query to the first 10 matching rows. He wants to display 10 results per page, and use "Next" and "Previous" buttons to page through them. And he wants someone else to write the code for him from scratch.

Comment: Please tell me the logic if you want i've had already tried many things for this purpose.

Comment: we can tell that OP obviously does not yet know how to page query results, therefore this answer is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

For your first page you will have to retrieve from your database your first 10 results, the 1, 2, 3 ... 9, 10 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 0, 10
```

and print out your results.
If, let's say the user is on page 4 you will have to retrieve from 31, 32, 33.. 39, 40 rows. Calculate your offset and row_count in a server script like PHP:

```
$page_no = 4;
$row_count = 10; 
$offset = ($page_no - 1) * $row_count; // results 30
```

Now your SQL will be:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 30, 10;
```

so you will have the 31, 32, 33... rows that you can print out.
The page number can be retrieved via GET or POST parameters.

Comment: Thanx I think this one will surely help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could of course print out the whole result and use jQuery to paginate through it:

```
<!-- Download jquery and link locally.  Directlinking to jQuery should only be used for testing purposes. -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageno = 0;
    var maxpageno = 0;
    function show(){
        if (pageno < 0) { pageno = 0}
        if (pageno > maxpageno) { pageno = maxpageno}
        $('#results tbody tr').hide();
        $('#results tbody tr.page'+pageno).show();
    }
</script>
<body onload="show();">
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM books";   
    //result is boolean for query other than SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE and EXPLAIN
    $result = $short_connect->query($sql);
    if (($result) && ($result->num_rows > 0))
    {
        $results = array();
        print "<table id=\"results\">\n<thead>\n<tr><th>id</th><th>title</th><th>isbn</th><th>ean</th><th>year</th></tr>\n
        <tr><td colspan=5>
        <a href=\"#null\" onclick=\"pageno = 0; show();\">&lt;&lt;</a>
        <a href=\"#null\" onclick=\"pageno--; show();\">&lt;</a>
        <a href=\"#null\" onclick=\"pageno++; show();\">&gt;</a>
        <a href=\"#null\" onclick=\"pageno = maxpageno; show();\">&gt;&gt;</a>
        </th></tr>\n
        </thead>\n<tbody>\n";  //table starter and header
        $i = 0;                       //start count
        $ipp = 10;                        //items per page
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
        {
            $rop = $i % $ipp;           //result on page
            $pno = floor($i / $ipp);        //page number
            $i++;                         //increase count
            print "<tr class=\"page$pno\"><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[1]</td><td>$row[2]</td><td>$row[3]</td><td>$row[4]</td></tr>\n";
        }
        print "</tbody>\n<tfoot><tr><td colspan=5>
        <a href=\"#null\" onclick=\"pageno = 0; show();\">&lt;&lt;</a>
        <a href=\"#null\" onclick=\"pageno--; show();\">&lt;</a>
        <a href=\"#null\" onclick=\"pageno++; show();\">&gt;</a>
        <a href=\"#null\" onclick=\"pageno = maxpageno; show();\">&gt;&gt;</a>
        </td></tr>\n</tfoot>\n</table>\n"; // footer
        $result->free();
    }
    $short_connect->close();
    print "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> maxpageno = $pno;</script>";
?>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanku for your answer.